# Create custom animations in Objective-C?

Tags: ios

I want to create a custom animation in iOS.
Suppose, I have a UIView displaying with its SubViews.I want to take its screenshot and split it in to four parts that should be lefttop, righttop, bottomleft, bottomright from middle and move every part to their corners.As lefttop should move to left top corner of UIView and right top should move to right top corner and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this one helps You But not Sure ,
first  set your frame positions after that change the position of frames whatever you want,
by default i'm taking

```
                 top.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,120);
                 bottom.frame=CGRectMake(0,315,320,145);
                 left.frame=CGRectMake(0,113,151,202);
                 right.frame=CGRectMake(175,113,151,202);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(tranform) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

after 3 seconds this method will call,

```
-(void)tranform{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                     animations:^{
                         top.frame=CGRectMake(0,-120,320,120);
                         bottom.frame=CGRectMake(0,480,320,145);
                         left.frame=CGRectMake(-151,113,151,202);
                         right.frame=CGRectMake(320,113,151,202);



                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

in above code top,bottom,left,right are the four views and i'm adding all those to self.view
and when click on particular but animation will happens regarding their respective frames.

Comment: I know how to animate but I think you have not read my question carefully what I want.I have solved it,after 6 hours I will upload it

Comment: here i'm taking four imageviews which are divide one full image into four parts when i click one particular button those four parts are moving from center to top,left,right and bottom with their respective positions.

Comment: and how split it to move and what about this top.frame=CGRectMake(top.frame); you are moving from its frame to same frame

Comment: As I have already said I have solved it,so I do not need it now,but as of now your and is correct so I am accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, it will take screenshot of current screen displaying divides it in to four equal parts from center and animate it to move to their respective corners.

```
- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"animation called ");
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.bounds.size);
    [self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGImageRef imgref=[image CGImage];
    NSArray *arrayOfImages= [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self splitImageIntoRects:imgref]];

    NSLog(@"array of images are %@",arrayOfImages);


    for (CALayer *layer in arrayOfImages) {
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    }

    [self animateLayers:arrayOfImages];
}

-(void)animateLayers:(NSArray*)array
{
    for (int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
    {
        CALayer *layer=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect rect=[layer frame];
        CGPoint newPt;

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                newPt=CGPointMake(-rect.size.width, -rect.size.height);
                break;
            case 1:
                newPt=CGPointMake(rect.origin.x-rect.size.width, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height);
                break;
            case 2:
                newPt=CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y-rect.size.height);
                break;
            case 3:
                newPt=CGPointMake(rect.origin.x+rect.size.width, rect.origin.y+rect.size.height);
                break;
        }
        [self moveLayer:layer to:newPt];
    }
}

-(void)moveLayer:(CALayer*)layer to:(CGPoint)point
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration=1;
    animation.fromValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];

    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    layer.position = point;
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
}

- (NSArray*)splitImageIntoRects:(CGImageRef)anImage{

    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(anImage), CGImageGetHeight(anImage));

    NSMutableArray *splitLayers = [NSMutableArray array];

    int kXSlices = 2;
    int kYSlices = 2;

    for(int x = 0;x < kXSlices;x++) {
        for(int y = 0;y < kYSlices;y++) {
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake((imageSize.width / kXSlices) * x,
                                      (imageSize.height / kYSlices) * y,
                                      (imageSize.width / kXSlices),
                                      (imageSize.height / kYSlices));

            CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
            layer.frame = frame;
            CGImageRef subimage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(anImage, frame);
            layer.contents = (__bridge id)subimage;
            CFRelease(subimage);
            [splitLayers addObject:layer];
        }
    }

    return splitLayers;
}
```